# RESTTemplate waiting for API response

Tags: java, web-services, spring, api, rest

In my Spring application I use RESTTemplate to get some information from external API. This API require that when you make a request you must to wait for response of it until you make another request. That's why I am wondering how to do this. Of course cannot use timer or something like that because response time from this API is different every time.

Unfortunately, RESTTemplate is required for this app and i cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly you should wait for a response when you make the request but you can open a server socket that is listening for incoming data and when you receive a response, check what kind of response it is then accept or reject it. So you make requests with a client socket and receive responses with a server socket.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a flag in a singleton bean to implement this. Before calling a service, check if it is `false`. If `false` make the flag `true` and call service. Before exiting make the flag `false`.

So when `flag == true` a service is in progress else you can place a new request.

Comment: I really dont understand how you can connect to an external api only using a boolean ...

Comment: @JonathanCruz Since he is using RESTTemplate the call to external api would be something like `String result = restTemplate.getForObject("...` He wants to make sure that there are no pending requests before making another call that can be triggered by the user. So just check for a flag set in some static class set the flag before calling and clear it after calling. So just before calling the api if he finds that the flag is true he can ask user ti try again later.